# How to set Array in select

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm using the `Selectize.js`, I have a field in a kind of search where the values ​​are set according to an array. I get the array with a request and desire set him in my select options. How can I do that?

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Selectize.js</h1>
            <div class="demo">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="select-tools">Tools:</label>
                    <select id="select-tools" placeholder="Buscar ag&ecirc;ncia..."></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This works

```
agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
    var embedded = data._embedded;
    $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.listaAgencias));
  }).catch(function (error) {
    alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });


  $('#select-tools').selectize({
    maxItems: null,
    valueField: 'nome',
    labelField: 'nome',
    searchField: 'nome',
    options: [
      {nome: 'Spectrometer'},
      {nome: 'Star Chart'},
      {nome: 'Electrical Tape'}
    ],
    create: false
  });
```

[image]

But I want something like this...

```
  agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
    var embedded = data._embedded;
    $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;
    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.listaAgencias));
  }).catch(function (error) {
    alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });


  $('#select-tools').selectize({
    maxItems: null,
    valueField: 'nome',
    labelField: 'nome',
    searchField: 'nome',
    options: $scope.listaAgencias,
    create: false
  });
```

But doesn't works
[image]

My $scope.listaAgencias is

```
[
   {
      "nome":"Agencia um",
      "createdBy":"anonymousUser",
      "lastModifiedBy":"anonymousUser",
      "createdAt":"2015-07-21T12:15:36.369+0000",
      "lastModified":"2015-07-21T12:15:36.369+0000",
      "_links":{
         "self":{
            "href":"http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37e8ccf2070af2e5ab1c"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "nome":"Agencia dois",
      "createdBy":"anonymousUser",
      "lastModifiedBy":"anonymousUser",
      "createdAt":"2015-07-21T12:15:41.286+0000",
      "lastModified":"2015-07-21T12:15:41.286+0000",
      "_links":{
         "self":{
            "href":"http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37edccf2070af2e5ab1d"
         }
      }
   }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put inside my GET request and works

```
  agenciasAPI.getAgencias().success(function (data) {
    var embedded = data._embedded;
    $scope.listaAgencias = embedded.agencias;


      $('#select-tools').selectize({
        maxItems: null,
        valueField: 'nome',
        labelField: 'nome',
        searchField: 'nome',
        options: embedded.agencias,
        create: false
      });

    alert(JSON.stringify($scope.listaAgencias));
  }).catch(function (error) {
    alert("Erro ao obter listagem de agencias");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  });
```

[image]